# Can a tiling on $\mathbb{R}^n$ continuously map to a tiling on $\mathbb{R}^m$ if $n > m$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $n, m$ be naturals such that $n > m$. Suppose $\mathbb{R}^n$ is tiled into finitely many regions. Each region must be disjoint, connected, continuous and have a nonzero measure.Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R^m}$ be continuous. **Is it possible for the images of regions in $\mathbb{R^m}$ to be non-intersecting. What if the number of regions is countably infinite? Are there any interesting restrictions on the tiling or the mapping that make this impossible?**

Here is one idea I had. Suppose a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $A$ and $f(A) = B$. We know that $B$. $A$ can border multiple regions while $B$ can only border two.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a tiling?

Comment: I suspect that you have restrictions on $f$ in mind that have not been specified.  Is it supposed to be linear?  continuous? or what? I can certainly chop $\Bbb R^m$ into the same number of pieces and make a function that takes one piece to one piece.  Cardinality says so.

Comment: I mean to divide up space into distinct regions. Each region must be connected and have a nonzero measure.

Comment: I forgot to add continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the trivial tilings of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$ consisting of one tile. The map
$$f:\ \Bbb{R}^n\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}^m:\ (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\ \longmapsto\ (x_1,\ldots,x_m),$$
is continuous and maps the one tile of $\Bbb{R}^n$ onto the one tile of $\Bbb{R}^m$.

More generally, assuming that a tiling is a partition: Given any partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $\Bbb{R}^m$, we can construct a partition $\mathcal{Q}$of $\Bbb{R}^n$ such that the map above has the desired properties. Describing the partition $\mathcal{P}$ as a collection $\{P_i\}_{i\in I}$ of subsets $P_i\subset\Bbb{R}^m$ such that $\bigcup_{i\in I}P_i=\Bbb{R}^m$ and $P_i\cap P_j=\varnothing$ whenever $i\neq j$, define 
$$Q_i:=P_i\times\Bbb{R}^{n-m}=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb{R}^n:\ (x_1,\ldots,x_m)\in P_i\}\subset\Bbb{R}^n.$$
It is not hard to verify that $\mathcal{Q}:=\{Q_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a partition of $\Bbb{R}^n$, and that $f(Q_i)=P_i$.

Comment: This shows that every partition of $\mathbb{R}^m$ corresponds to a partition of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to see the other way around.

Comment: Then you should have asked that; in stead you asked whether it is possible for a tiling of $\Bbb{R}^n$ to map continuously into a tiling of $\Bbb{R}^m$. My answer shows that this is possible, and even gives an example *for every tiling of $\Bbb{R}^m$*.